# Cypher query to check locations and sublocations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Profile node which may be linked to Location node via :LOCATED_IN relationship.
In turn, Location represents unlimited composite structure of nested Location nodes linked with :CONTAINS relationships between them.

I need to find all Profiles which linked to specified location IDs or their parent locations on unlimited levels.

I'm trying to create such Cypher query but it doesn't work as expected. This is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (d:Profile)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(l:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (pl:Location)-[:CONTAINS*]->(l) 
WHERE any(x IN l.id WHERE x IN [100,34]) OR any(x IN pl.id WHERE x IN [100,34]) 
RETURN d;
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this could work

```
WITH [100,34]  AS locationIDs

// get paths, starting at root, ending at the nodes I need
MATCH locationPath=(root:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (()-[:CONTAINS]->(root))
      AND id(descendant) IN (locationIDs+[id(root)])

// create a collection of unique nodes on the locationPaths
UNWIND nodes(locationPath) AS pathNode
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT pathNode) AS pathNodes

// find profiles linked to at least one of the pathNodes
MATCH (d:Profile)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(pathNode)
WHERE pathNode IN pathNodes
RETURN d
```

Comment: Thanks! It partially works. Partially, because looks like it doesn't take the `root` location into account, but the `root` should also be evaluated with `IN locationIDs`. How to add this logic also?

Comment: For instance - it doesn't work when `Profile` is associated(via `LOCATED_IN`) with location `ID = 2` and I use `WITH [2]  AS locationIDs`

Comment: You are right.. i improved the answer

Comment: Sorry.. looks like it also doesn't work. This query will always return any Profile which have relationship with any Location.

Comment: Could it be the typo CONTANS instead of CONTAINS (corrected) ? Sorry doing this on a mobile so hard to test

Comment: Thanks but  I already fixed the typo and it still doesn't work. Looks like the following do the right trick - `AND (id(descendant) IN (locationIDs) or id(root) IN (locationIDs))` I need to test it more carefully but on the first look it works..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should start from the `Location` node and work your way up to the `Profile` node.

```
MATCH (l:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->()-[:LOCATED_IN]-(p:Profile)
WHERE l.id IN [100,34]
RETURN distinct p
```

So you identify your start Location by id.
Then use the `CONTAINS*0..`, which means that it should traverse the `CONTAINS` relationship from zero hops (meaning that it can skip it) to theoretically infinite hops and look if any of those nodes have a profile attached to it.

I'm not sure if parent location is a directed `CONTAINS` relationship from child to parent, but judging from your initial query it is. Other than that, I think it should work.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems that this returns the profiles linked to the specified locations and their children. The question is though to find profiles linked to the specified location and their parents.